# Update UIDocument in LotusNotes

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus

I have been working on a Notes integration project and I am using the Domingo API for communicating with Lotus Notes. This API is very useful, however I don't see any NotesUIDocument class and limited support for RichText in Lotus Notes. I have checked in the Notes.jar file and even that jar file seems to miss the NotesUIDocument functionality. Does anybody know of any alternative for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NotesUIDocument` is a LotusScript class which works because LotusScript support is embedded into the Notes client UI. When using Java, you generally work with the back-end classes such as `Document` (`NotesDocument` in LotusScript).

Why do you need access to `NotesUIDocument` from Java? Any possible alternative may depend on your specific needs.

**Update:** I don't believe you'll be able to get tight UI integration between the Notes client and a Java application. In terms of rich text, the Java classes in Notes.jar include a set of classes for rich text manipulation which will cater for the basic functionality, but you won't get as much rich text editing flexibility as you do through the Notes UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using LS2J this allows you to use lotusscript for all the front end stuff and allows you to call your java back-end code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note - I believe support for *some* UI classes in the Java API is planned for the Domino 8.5.2 release. But, these will only be useful if you Java integration code runs within a Notes client.

Answer (score 0):

The current state of play is **no** UI support from the java api :-(

As @edSchembor mentioned 8.5.2 is rumoured to have some UI support coming but don't hold your breath in terms of what mileage you'll get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

As per 8.5.2 the Java UI API exists. You can refer to the Lotus wiki [Here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Notes_Client_Java_UI_APIs-v8.5.2&ei=fDnKTtygDMPi4QS10cg0&usg=AFQjCNHjzkky7RWToZSKWD_Sy8PI2fsG5w)

You could use this API with the ability to create Eclipse RCP plug-ins for Lotus Notes to enhance the Notes UI.